# valgrind shows memory leak even after memory free

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, valgrind

so I have the file Countries.c which contains:

```
typedef struct City* pCity;
typedef struct Country* pCountry;
typedef struct Territory* pTerritory;
struct City{
    char* name;
    char* food;
    int population;

};

struct Country{
    char *name;
    int numCities;
    pCity cities;
    pTerritory countryTerr;

};

struct Territory{
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int y1;
    int y2;
};
void deleteCountry(pCountry country){
    if(country != NULL){
        int num_of_cities = country->numCities;
        for(int i = 0 ; i<num_of_cities; i++){
            if (country->cities !=NULL){
               if (country->cities[i].food)
                    free(country->cities[i].food);

                if (country->cities[i].name)
                        free(country->cities[i].name);
            }
        }
        if (country->name != NULL){
            free(&(country->name));
        }
        //free(country);
    }
}

pCountry addCountry(char* name,int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){
    if(name==NULL)
        return NULL;
    pCountry newCountry = NULL;
    newCountry = (pCountry)malloc(sizeof(struct Country));
    if(newCountry==NULL){
        free(newCountry);
        return NULL;
    }
    newCountry->name = (char*)malloc((strlen(name)+1)*sizeof(char));
    newCountry->countryTerr = (pTerritory)malloc(sizeof(struct Territory));
    if(newCountry->name)
        strcpy(newCountry->name,name);
    newCountry->numCities=0;
    if(newCountry->countryTerr){
        newCountry->countryTerr->x1=x1;
        newCountry->countryTerr->y1=y1;
        newCountry->countryTerr->x2=x2;
        newCountry->countryTerr->y2=y2;
    }
    return newCountry;
}


status addCity(pCountry country,pCity city){
    if (country==NULL || city==NULL)
        return failure;

    if(country->numCities==0)
        country->cities = (pCity)malloc(sizeof(struct City));
    else
        country->cities =(pCity)realloc(country->cities,(country->numCities+1)*sizeof(struct City));

    if(!country->cities)
            return failure;

    country->cities[country->numCities] = *city;
    country->numCities++;
    return success;
}
```

now, In the start of the program, I add some countries using the "addCountry"

function which stored in array of struct pointers.

and then In the end when the user presses to exit, I call to the delete country

for each country, and yet when I checked for memory leak with valgrind,

It shows that I do have memory leak from the "addCounrty", here is the log:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==86249==     in use at exit: 918 bytes in 12 blocks
==86249==   total heap usage: 28 allocs, 16 frees, 7,248 bytes allocated
==86249== 
==86249== Searching for pointers to 12 not-freed blocks
==86249== Checked 68,888 bytes
==86249== 
==86249== 22 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6
==86249==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==86249==    by 0x109150: addCountry (Countries.c:101)
==86249==    by 0x10A310: add_parsed_country (main.c:214)
==86249==    by 0x10A14A: parse_file (main.c:180)
==86249==    by 0x109A3E: main (main.c:17)
==86249== 
==86249== 32 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 6
==86249==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==86249==    by 0x109164: addCountry (Countries.c:102)
==86249==    by 0x10A310: add_parsed_country (main.c:214)
==86249==    by 0x10A14A: parse_file (main.c:180)
==86249==    by 0x109A3E: main (main.c:17)
==86249== 
==86249== 96 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 6
==86249==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==86249==    by 0x109260: addCity (Countries.c:123)
==86249==    by 0x10A3DF: add_parsed_city (main.c:233)
==86249==    by 0x10A1AA: parse_file (main.c:188)
==86249==    by 0x109A3E: main (main.c:17)
==86249== 
==86249== 96 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 6
==86249==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==86249==    by 0x10984A: citySetter (Countries.c:210)
==86249==    by 0x10A3C8: add_parsed_city (main.c:232)
==86249==    by 0x10A1AA: parse_file (main.c:188)
==86249==    by 0x109A3E: main (main.c:17)
==86249== 
==86249== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 6
==86249==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==86249==    by 0x4EBBB8B: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:62)
==86249==    by 0x10A1C1: parse_file (main.c:176)
==86249==    by 0x109A3E: main (main.c:17)
==86249== 
==86249== LEAK SUMMARY:
==86249==    definitely lost: 366 bytes in 11 blocks
==86249==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==86249==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==86249==    still reachable: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
==86249==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==86249== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==86249== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==86249== 
==86249== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==86249== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

why is that?

Comment: Your call `free(&(country->name))` is wrong and leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Good catch, @Someprogrammerdude, but inasmuch as `name` is the first member of `struct Country`, it is rather the case that `free(&(country->name))` is equivalent to `free(country)`.  That's surely not what the OP intended, and it likely explains at least some of the failures to free, but in itself it is not wrong and does not produce UB.

Comment: I observe, too, that there is a commented-out `free(country)` in the OP's code.  Since the OP is analyzing this code with Valgrind, I'd be inclined to speculate that that arises from the OP peviously correcting a Valgrind multiple-free error arising from the same underlying mistake.  Commenting out the other `free` would have silenced such an error, but for the wrong reason.

Comment: I think deleteCountry should also free the countryTerr and cities fields of the country

Answer (score 0):

I can see that addCountry returns newCountry. Are you freeing it after function call? Also avoid casting malloc.